# Connecting to web hosting site via git in such a way that I can push and pull directly via my local pc

Tags: git-push, git-pull, git-clone, git-remote, git-add

I initialized a bare repository on server

```
git init --bare
```

and then added a remote

```
git remote add origin my.hosting.website.com:my-repository.git
```

then I am trying to pull.I used

```
pull -all my repo on server
```

Problem is when I try to pull/push an item it gives error message

```
fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Sorry I am just new to git.

Comment: By the way Is it appropiate to use this guide as it contains checkout command , which can be dangerous to use .

Comment: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

Comment: Checkout can be dangerous, but it's also the command to switch branches - a safe, common, necessary function. You might want to do some more reading if you're worried, until you understand the commands better.

Comment: I am a beginner git user who uses git to maintain version control between his machine and his repo , usually I  I have rarely used checkout commands. Usually I use add ,commit , push and pull commands.

Comment: There are other developers who use the hosting web server , is using git variable like GIT_WORKING_TREE and then using hook as mentioned in the link is the only way to connect to server ?